# How to test details, delete etc

Tags: python, django, testing, python-unittest

I have this url:

```
url(r'^detail/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.Details.as_view(), name='detail'),
```

My test:

```
def test_detail(self):
    resp = self.client.get("/detail/")
    self.assertEqual(resp.status_code, 200)
```

In my test results I get:

```
AssertionError: 404 != 200
```

How test this?

Comment: what does `reverse` do?

Comment: @adarsh Get the name of url

Comment: I would personally prefer writing the url by hand because that way the test is "easier" to break, say, if reverse was just complementing bad behaviour. Anyways, try printing the value of what that returns. And is there any other reason why your view code might return a 404?

Comment: URL is expecting a `pk` -  which is not optional. Hence the 404. Unless you have another target which specifically matches `/detail`, example: `url(r'^detail/$'` this is bound to fail.

Answer (score 2):

Your detail view url entry requires a detail to fetch

`reverse('detail', args=[your_detail.pk])`

In your test that is erroring the `pk` is not being matched because you are not including a value.

Comment: I do that: resp = self.client.get(reverse("detail", kwargs={'pk': 1})) and get: NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'detail' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'pk': 1}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Comment: 0 patterns tried! is your app registered? Is your url entry in your apps `urls.py` or in your projects? is your entry namespaced?